# Installing R Studio with Anaconda

Tags: r, anaconda, rstudio

I tried to install R Studio (version 1.1.456) using the anaconda navigator by simply clicking on the install button. It was taking more than an hour, so I just figured it should be stuck.
I then tried to install it through the anaconda prompt but now it has also been stuck for around 30 minutes here:

[image]

What can I do to get around this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

For various reasons up-to-date RStudio versions are not availabe on any conda channel I know. @merv's answer is the easiest solution, if you are happy to work with an older version of rstudio. Here is another suggestion, where you install RStudio outside of conda, but configure it to use a particular R installation, which is maintained in your custom conda environment. Step by step, this is how you procede:

1. Install the latest RStudio from the [official sources](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download)
2. Create your custom conda environment `CUSTOMENV`, including an installation of r-base

   ```
   conda create -n CUSTOMENV -c conda-forge r-base'>=4.0.0' ... [further packages]
   ```
3. Activate the conda environment

   ```
   conda activate CUSTOMENV
   ```
4. Start RStudio from console

   ```
   rstudio &
   ```

Comment: Conda Forge's `r-base` package already includes [an `activate-r-base.sh` script](https://github.com/conda-forge/r-base-feedstock/blob/master/recipe/activate-r-base.sh) that manages the `RSTUDIO_WHICH_R` variable during activation.

Comment: As @merv has commented, in 2021, you don't have to go through steps 3-5. Just follow steps 1, 2, and 6 (although for step 6, I used "rstudio" without the "&", and it seems to work fine).

Comment: @aysljc the LD_LIBRARY_PATH may still be needed since it is likely essential to any subsequent compilation from within an R session (e.g., installing a non-Conda package from source or using rstan). The `&` is so one can continue using the shell session; otherwise it waits for the process to exit. Just a matter of convenience.

Comment: Actually, has anybody tried running the RStudio installer from within an activated conda-environment? Maybe that would automatically find the right setting for LD_LIBRARY_PATH (and possibly other environemtn variables, we have not yet considered).

Answer (score 5):

**Important Note:** I strongly endorse [@mfakaehler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63336611/570918) since all RStudio builds on Conda have effectively been abandoned. Install RStudio natively and launch from activated environment.

---

Create a new env instead. E.g.,

```
conda create --name rstudio_env -c r rstudio
```

Best practice for Conda is to create new envs for each project rather than using a monolithic **base** env. Generally, I find that the less one installs in **base** the better their experience with Conda will be.