# can't launch rstudio from a conda environment

Tags: qt, conda

I was trying to launch rstudio from a conda environment that has R 4.1.0 and it gives me that error

```
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How can I solve this issue without being the admin on my computer?

One thing that I changed after creating the environment is

```
conda env config vars set LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test2c2/lib"

conda env config vars set RSTUDIO_WHICH_R="/wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test2c2/bin/R"
```

I did this because I had an issue in loading Seurat before described in details in this question [libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69288536/libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-26-not-found-on-linux)

when I tried exporting QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and launching rstudio again, it gave this

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 330241
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/platforms" ...
Cannot load library /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/../lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test2/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5))
QLibraryPrivate::loadPlugin failed on "/usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so" : "Cannot load library /usr/lib/rstudio/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so: (/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/../lib/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.12' not found (required by /wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test2/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5))"
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"
in "".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?

the command `which R` gives `/wdata/msmuhammad/workbench/miniconda3/envs/test2/bin/R` and `which rstudio` gives `/usr/bin/rstudio`

Comment: Since the source of conflict is RStudio's required dependencies being masked by the ones in the Conda environment, I'd try to see if the Qt stuff (`lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5`) in the Conda environment is even necessary. I run similar setup (though on MacOS), and none of my Conda R environments have Qt libraries installed. I've found Mamba's `mamba repoquery whoneeds --tree` command super useful for identifying what packages are drawing in particular dependencies.